# showing me null pointer exception,couldn't figure out the reason

Tags: android

## Activity Class :

```
package com.bioscope.backup_old;

import java.util.ArrayList;



import com.bioscope.R;
import com.bioscope.main.EventDescriptionActivity;
import com.bioscope.main.EventListActivity;
import com.bioscope.main.HomeActivity;
import com.bioscope.model.EventModel;


import com.bioscope.server.RecieveEventsTask;
import com.bioscope.utility.EventsListAdapter;
import com.bioscope.utility.Utility;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.view.MenuItemCompat;
import android.support.v4.view.MenuItemCompat.OnActionExpandListener;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.TextView.OnEditorActionListener;

public class MyEventList extends Activity{

    private ListView list;
    private MenuItem myActionMenuItem;
    private EditText txtSearch;
    private TextView myActionTextView;



    private ArrayList <EventModel>eventsList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(com.bioscope.R.layout.myevent_list);

        RecieveEventsTask task = new RecieveEventsTask(this, "all");
        task.execute();

        //getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);





    }


        public void showEventsDataLoaded(ArrayList<EventModel> eventsList) {

             this.eventsList = eventsList;

    for(EventModel e:eventsList )
        {

            Log.v("title", e.getTitle());   
        }

        EventsListAdapter adapter=new EventsListAdapter(com.bioscope.backup_old.MyEventList.this, eventsList);

        list=(ListView) findViewById(com.bioscope.R.id.listView1);

        list.setAdapter(adapter);

        list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                //Toast.makeText(EventList.this, "You Clicked an item ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                  showEventInformaion(position);  

            }
        });

        }

        public void showCategoryListDataLoaded(String response)
        {
            Utility.showMessage(this, response);

        }

        private void showEventInformaion(int position)
        {

            Intent i=new Intent(MyEventList.this, EventDescriptionActivity.class);

            Bundle b = new Bundle();

            Log.v("selected", eventsList.get(position).getTitle());

            MyEventDescription.eventInfo = eventsList.get(position);

            Log.v("selected", MyEventDescription.eventInfo.getTitle());

            //i.putExtra("eventInfo", eventsList.get(position));
            startActivity(i);

        }






    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu items for use in the action bar

        /** Create an option menu from res/menu/items.xml */
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.editlist_menu, menu);

        /** Get the action view of the menu item whose id is search */ 
        View v = (View) menu.findItem(R.id.search).getActionView();



        txtSearch = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.myActionEditText);
          /** Setting an action listener */
            txtSearch.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Search : " + v.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return false;
                }
            });  





        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle presses on the action bar items
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case com.bioscope.R.id.search:
                //openSearch();
                Toast.makeText (this,"You clicked on the Application icon",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return true;
            case R.id.home:
                MenuItemCompat.collapseActionView(myActionMenuItem);
                Toast.makeText (this,"You clicked on the Application icon",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                //openHomeSettings();
                return true;
            case R.id.tohome:
                Toast.makeText (this,"You clicked on the Home icon",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                openHomeSettings();
                return true;

            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    private void openHomeSettings()
    {
        Intent i=new Intent(MyEventList.this, HomeActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
        finish();

    }

    private void showEventInformaion()
    {

        Intent i=new Intent(MyEventList.this, MyEventDescription.class);
        startActivity(i);   

    }




    }
```

## ReceiveEventTask

I have already check whether the context is null or not. I am  using the
  same task class for another activity which is working perfectly but for this MyEventList activity it's showing nullpointer     exception

```
public class RecieveEventsTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{

    ProgressDialog dialog;
    String responseString;

    EventListActivity appContext;
    MyEventList my_appContext;

    String url;
    String pageUrl="event-list";

    //String name,email,pass,phone;



    public RecieveEventsTask(EventListActivity c,String critiria)
    {
        appContext=c;
        //url = Utility.baseUrl + pageUrl + critiria;
        url = "http://bioscopebd.com/mobileappand/geteventlist";
    }

    public RecieveEventsTask(MyEventList c,String critiria)
    {
        my_appContext=c;
        //url = Utility.baseUrl + pageUrl + critiria;
        url = "http://bioscopebd.com/mobileappand/getmyeventlist";
    }
    protected void onPreExecute(){

        dialog = new ProgressDialog(appContext==null?my_appContext:appContext);
        dialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER); 
        dialog.setMessage("Loading Events...");
        dialog.show();
        super.onPreExecute();

    }

    String filterResponseString(String r)
    {
        return r.replace("\r\n", "");
    }


    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... uri) {

        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpResponse response;

        try {

            response = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet(url));
            StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();

            if(statusLine.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK){

                ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                response.getEntity().writeTo(out);
                out.close();
                responseString = out.toString();
                responseString=filterResponseString(responseString);

            } 
            else
            {
                //Closes the connection.
               response.getEntity().getContent().close();

               Utility.showMessage(appContext, "Cannot Connect To Internet");
            }
        }  
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            //TODO Handle problems..
        }
        return responseString;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) 
    {
        dialog.dismiss();

        if(responseString!=null)
        {
            ArrayList<EventModel> eventsList = new ArrayList<EventModel>(); ;
            JSONArray jsonArr;


            try {

                //Log.v("json", responseString);

                jsonArr = new JSONArray(responseString);
                //jsonArr = events.getJSONArray("events");


                for(int i=0;i<jsonArr.length();i++)
                {
                    JSONObject jsonObj =  jsonArr.getJSONObject(i);

                    EventModel event = new EventModel();

                   event.setTitle(jsonObj.getString("event_info_title"));
                   event.setDescription(jsonObj.getString("event_info_desc"));

                    Log.v("logo data "+i, jsonObj.getString("image_logo"));

                    //event.setBanner(jsonObj.getString("image_banner"));
                    event.setLogo(jsonObj.getString("image_logo"));


                    eventsList.add(event);

                }


            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            if(appContext!=null)
            {
            appContext.showEventsDataLoaded(eventsList);

            }
            else
            {
                Log.v("check:","null");

            }

            if(my_appContext!=null)
            {
            my_appContext.showEventsDataLoaded(eventsList);

            }
            else
            {
                Log.v("check:","null");

            }

        }

        super.onPostExecute(result);
        //Do anything with response..
    }
```

## logCat

can anyone explain me the reason,would be helpful

```
11-10 03:18:29.610: E/AndroidRuntime(1273): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-10 03:18:29.610: E/AndroidRuntime(1273): Process: com.bioscope, PID: 1273
11-10 03:18:29.610: E/AndroidRuntime(1273): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.bioscope/com.bioscope.backup_old.MyEventList}: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-10 03:18:29.610: E/AndroidRuntime(1273):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
11-10 03:18:29.610: E/AndroidRuntime(1273):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
11-10 03:18:29.610: E/AndroidRuntime(1273):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
11-10 03:18:29.610: E/AndroidRuntime(1273):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
11-10 03:18:29.610: E/AndroidRuntime(1273):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
11-10 03:18:29.610: E/AndroidRuntime(1273):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
11-10 03:18:29.610: E/AndroidRuntime(1273):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
11-10 03:18:29.610: E/AndroidRuntime(1273):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-10 03:18:29.610: E/AndroidRuntime(1273):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
11-10 03:18:29.610: E/AndroidRuntime(1273):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
11-10 03:18:29.610: E/AndroidRuntime(1273):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
11-10 03:18:29.610: E/AndroidRuntime(1273):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-10 03:18:29.610: E/AndroidRuntime(1273): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-10 03:18:29.610: E/AndroidRuntime(1273):     at com.bioscope.backup_old.MyEventList.onCreate(MyEventList.java:67)
11-10 03:18:29.610: E/AndroidRuntime(1273):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
11-10 03:18:29.610: E/AndroidRuntime(1273):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
11-10 03:18:29.610: E/AndroidRuntime(1273):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
11-10 03:18:29.610: E/AndroidRuntime(1273):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: Piyush is right you have to initialize your array list.

Comment: whare you declare eventsList in activity.  @piyush is right

Comment: now this is embarrassing :/

Comment: Debug and see if adapter is null?

Comment: my_appContext.showEventsDataLoaded(eventsList) in receivertask showing me null @MysticMagic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the mistake. In my layout of the activity i had a listview which had a different id and that's why it was showing me a null pointer exception

Answer (score 3):

Initialize your `eventsList` `ArrayList` on `onCreate()` method. it is null.

```
eventsList = new ArrayList <EventModel>();
```

Comment: But it's showing me the same error after doing this. I am loading the value in eventsList in EventsDataLoaded(ArrayList<EventModel> eventsList) method

Comment: list.setAdapter(adapter);

Comment: Remove from onCreate EventsListAdapter adapter=new EventsListAdapter(MyEventList.this, eventsList);

        list= (ListView)findViewById(com.bioscope.R.id.listView1);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);

        list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(MyEventList.this, "You Clicked an item ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    showEventInformaion(); });

Comment: yeah i already found that and fixed it but now showing me exception in my receivertask class in the line my_appContext.showEventsDataLoaded(eventsList);

Comment: @FaymeShahriar Because your Context are different so.

Comment: You need to use same type of Context for your receivertask class

Comment: no i can use different context if i am calling one at a time,i have already done that before so that's not the case